# Is it possible to await multiprocessing.Process.join() in python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

Basically what I am asking is, if there is a "`await p.join()`" function, which awaits a separate Process, while letting the event loop in the main process do other stuff.

I have a python-asyncio architecture in a FastAPI application. In case I have a long running and CPU heavy operation I would like to handle it in a separate Process, something like the following toy example:

```
def heavy_duty(input: InputModel) -> None:
    # long running calculation here

async def process(input: InputModel) -> None:

    p = Process(target=heavy_duty, args=(input,))
    p.start()
    await p.join() # give up event loop and wait for heavy duty to finish while main process can do other stuff
```

Would this be possible to do in the described way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as far as I can tell my problem seems to be simply solved by using the event loops `run_in_executor`:

```
def heavy_duty(input: InputModel) -> None:
    # long running calculation here

async def process(input: InputModel) -> None:

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, heavy_duty, input)
```

Comment: Yes, ProcessPoolExecutor is a higher level api you should use if possible. Otherwise, to `await`  a "normal" `process.join`, you should _also_ dellegate it to an executor - but in this case you could use the default loop executor which will simply run the `.join` call in another thread.passing `None` as the first parameter to `.run_in_executor`.