# BufferError in Pycharm Debugger when using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, multiprocessing

I have the following bit of code in a FastAPI application (derived from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538125/is-it-possible-to-await-multiprocessing-process-join-in-python)):

```
with self.lock:
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        return await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, self._generate_model, input_data
        )
```

Basically `input_data` is a `pydantic.BaseModel` and `_generate_model()` is a class method doing some heavy calculation.
This bit of code runs perfectly fine in VSCode and using "run" in PyCharm. However, debugging in Pycharm crashes the application as soon as this section is executed a **second** time with:

```
Exception ignored in tp_clear of: <class 'memoryview'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "some_file.py", line xxx # this is different everytime it happens
BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer
```

Google has let me down so far, what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

The Task Manager shows many processes(depend on how many processes are pooled) are still running even the debug is stopped. It works for me to end all Pycharm tasks in Task Manager and reopen Pycharm and redebug.